# Как сделать кнопку поделиться записью в соц сети для любых страниц сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook, соцсети

Есть кнопки соц сетей с собственным дизайном. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на каждую кнопку человек мог поделиться записью с другими пользователями на своей странице. Для контакта и фейсбука нашел, где `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` текущая страница на wordpress

```html
<div>
<p>Какой-то текст</p>
<p>Поделиться</p>
<div class="social_icons_holder">
  <ul class="social_icons clearfix">
    <li class="facebook">
      <span class="tool-tip">Facebook</span>       
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Поделиться в Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="instagram">
      <span class="tool-tip">Instagram</span>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="vk">
      <span class="tool-tip">Vkontakte</span>
<a href="https://vk.com/share.php?url=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Поделиться ВКонтакте"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="foursquare">
      <span class="tool-tip">Foursquare</span>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://ru.foursquare.com/"><i class="demo-icon icon-foursquare-1"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--/ .social-icons-->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: У каждой из соцсетей есть свой механизм для этого. Например у facebook про это написано тут: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button . Единого механизма не существует.

Comment: @Vartlok хорошо, давайте на примере фейсбука - как мне добавить кнопку так, чтобы та страница на которой я нахожусь добавлялась в поделиться пользователю. для каждой страницы и поста создавать собственную кнопку?

Answer (score 1):

На примере фейсбука: 
Рабочий пример [тут](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xpx8czd8rudpu9k/shareButton.html?dl=0).

1. Нужно [зарегистрировать](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) свое приложение, чтобы получить app id и app secret.
2. На сайт нужно подключить Facebook SDK. Это делается после регистрации своего приложения.
3. После этого вставляем на свой сайт кнопку. Чтобы div был динамичным, оставляем параметр data-href="" пустым. Еще можно написать функцию, которая возвращает адрес страницы, на которой вы находитесь. Но тогда придется распечатывать div с помощью javascript.
   Например:

```js
  getCurrentUrl();
function share() {
 window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='
 + window.location.href;
}

function getCurrentUrl() {
 return window.location.href;
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='share()'>Button</button>
<div data-href="" data-layout="button"></div>
```